# Why did everything electrical start malfunctioning in my house?

Tags: electrical, wiring

Lights are flickering, vacuum barely works.. I unplugged water heater and all my lights went out..plugged it back in and boom lights are back on.. If multiple circuits are malfunctioning shouldnt this be a ground break.. I crawled through atic and was shocked by a gas line that is dead.. All appliances are electric now.. Im on a budget and need help.. None of my space heaters work.. I moved into this house a month ago and everything worked properly this happened during the night woke up to electrical chaos

Comment: Check your coltage in *many* receptacles.  If some are 120 and others are less, you lost a hot service wire, and this is a call the power company and report an outage and they should send someone for free.   If some are less and others more than 120, *yet they add up to 240V*, then you lost your neutral!!  This is much more dangerous! Shut off the main and unplug anything you care about, and **call the power company and report an outage** urgently!  Good news, if a lost neutral you can still use 240V-only loads like electric heaters and water heaters.

Comment: True on 240v stuff but turn off all the 120v breakers or you may have smoked a lot of electronic devices.

Comment: @Harper sounds like an answer...

Comment: Get a wall socket tester from any big box hardware store.  They cost about 5$.  There are 3 led lights which will tell you what the problem is on each socket you test.

Answer (score 4):

### Call your power company and report an outage

When half your 120V circuits are dead and half work -- and the dead half comes back on when you turn on an oven or water heater or dryer (but those things don't work) -- that means **one of your hot wires has failed** coming from the power company.  It also may be a problem with the main buses or main breaker.

Now, if your 240V loads like water heater work fine, but lights alternate between too-dim and too-bright/burning out, that's a more serious problem - yes, *more serious than an outage*.  It is a **lost neutral**, and it will cause your 120V loads to wobble above and below 120V, which can fry appliances and potentially cause a fire.